# Handling a smooth movement over slopes in a worms like game

Tags: 2d, mathematics

I currently have a worms like game with the worms style pixel perfect terrain destruction. Its working well for pushing things around and watching them fall, but for the players movement it feels like your dragging your butt around rather than sliding around.
The code I use for the moving is the following:

```
private void tryMove() {

    float travelAngle = getSlopeNormal().angle() + (direction == -1 ? 180 : 0);

    while(travelAngle > 360) travelAngle -= 360;

    Vector2 travelVelocity = new Vector2(1, 1);

    travelVelocity.setAngle(travelAngle);

    Vector2 newPosition = getPosition().add(travelVelocity);

    boolean collision = false;

    for(float r = travelAngle - (float) Math.PI / 2F; r < travelAngle + Math.PI / 2.0F; r += Math.PI / 128){


        int testPosX = (int) (getRadius() * Math.cos(r) + newPosition.x);
        int testPosY = (int) (getRadius() * Math.sin(r) + newPosition.y + getMaximumStepUp());

        if (getMatch().getTerrain().isSolid(testPosX, getMatch().getTerrain().getHeight() - testPosY)) {

            collision = true;

            break;

        }


    }

    if(!collision){
        setPosition(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
        setVelocity(travelVelocity.scl(3));

    }


}
```

It works well for 'some' cases but other times feels like the player is always being dragged around and I apply the velocity at the end because otherwise the player can scale down walls 90-degrees. I feel there must be a better solution. I already have multiplayer systems in but with this movement code its causing all sorts of desyncs so I need a more reliable method.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the observable symptoms of this "dragging"  vs "sliding" feeling?

Comment: Here's a video of it in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H92rEfexzc
It's a very slight dragging feeling but definitely there. Its not smooth like Worms. Also, it gets stuck on terrain it shouldn't and clings to edges way to much. You can almost go to 90 degree angles if you go slow enough. I feel there must be a better algorithm out there to calculate movement

Comment: I'm trying to get an effect more similar to this: https://youtu.be/b2otrSSLyEE?t=1154 
In the game 'arcanists' they seem to simply walk around on the terrain but for my game they kind of drag or bounce around. Additionally, my version doesnt seem very determinant since it desyncs (with the server) around any complex terrain very quickly